# Closed set with finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Assume $F\subset \mathbb R$ is closed and $\mu(F)<\infty$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Can we deduce that $F$ is bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot conclude that $F$ is bounded. For a counterexample consider $F = \mathbb{N}$.